ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE using LVM_GETITEMPOSITION
I'm trying to retrieve the positions of the desktop icons.
I do get the right item count, but for the positions I always get 0, 0.
If I check for the last error I get ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE, which is strange for me since it's the same handle I used to get the item count.
Anyone has an idea of what I do wrong?
package main

import "core:fmt"
import "core:c"
import win32 "core:sys/windows"
import "base:runtime"

HWND :: win32.HWND
LPARAM :: win32.LPARAM
WPARAM :: win32.WPARAM


main :: proc() {

    hwnd_progman : HWND = win32.FindWindowA("Progman", "Program Manager");

    if (hwnd_progman == nil) {
        fmt.println("Progman not found! :(");
        return;
    }

    hwnd_shelldll_defview : HWND = win32.FindWindowExA(hwnd_progman, nil, "SHELLDLL_DefView", nil);
    
    if (hwnd_shelldll_defview == nil) {
        hwnd_shelldll_defview = win32.FindWindowExA(nil, nil, "SHELLDLL_DefView", nil);
    }

    if (hwnd_shelldll_defview == nil) {
        fmt.println("SHELLDLL_DefView not found! :(");
        return;
    }

    
    hwnd_listview : HWND = win32.FindWindowExA(hwnd_shelldll_defview, nil, "SysListView32", nil);
    if (hwnd_listview == nil) {
        fmt.println("SysListView32 not found! :(");
        return;
    }
    
    item_count : int = win32.SendMessageA(hwnd_listview, win32.LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
    
    fmt.printf("hwnd_progman: %v\n", hwnd_progman);
    fmt.printf("hwnd_shelldll_defview: %v\n", hwnd_shelldll_defview);
    fmt.printf("hwnd_listview: %v\n", hwnd_listview);
    fmt.printf("item_count: %v\n", item_count);


    for i in 0..< item_count {
        point: win32.POINT = win32.POINT{};
        result  := win32.SendMessageA(hwnd_listview, win32.LVM_GETITEMPOSITION, WPARAM(i), LPARAM(uintptr(&point)));
        if (result == 0) {
            error_code := win32.GetLastError();
            fmt.printf("error_code : %v\n", error_code);
            // 1400 which is ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE 

        }
        fmt.printf("result : %v\n", result );
        fmt.printf("x: %v y: %v\n", point.x, point.y);
    }
}

The output is as follow:
hwnd_progman: 0x10198
hwnd_shelldll_defview: 0x1019A
hwnd_listview: 0x1019C
item_count: 18
error_code : 0
result : 0
x: 0 y: 0
error_code : 1400
result : 0
x: 0 y: 0
error_code : 1400
result : 0
x: 0 y: 0
...


You can't pass an address in your process to another process, which is what you're doing to retrieve the positions. You need to allocate memory in the target process using VirtualAlloc.

Don't avoid using the documented API: Manipulating the positions of desktop icons.
